# Не могу обратиться к элементу Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragment

Учусь работать с навигацией, в видеоролике автор смог обратится к тексту который находится во фрагменте. А я не могу FindViewById тоже не помогает.
Мой код:

```
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)

view.textView.setOnClickListener{ 
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_secondFragment_to_firstFragment)
}

return view
```

В этом примере у меня подчеркивается **textView**

Вот код из видео , автор там не использует viewBinding и т.п

```
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)

view.textView.setOnClickListener{ 
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_secondFragment_to_firstFragment)
}

return view
```

У него нечего не подчеркивается и нет ошибок.
В чем может быть проблема ?
Вот видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DI0NIk-7cz8&list=PLSrm9z4zp4mHilvsfUM3jeCYFV3fTAS3J&index=3

Comment: автор ролика использует Kotlin synthetics, поэтому у него и находит. Kotlin synthetics не рекомендуется и считается устаревшим (на самом деле, он просто небезопасный) . либо по старинке через `findViewByID` либо `viewBinding`